# jQuery Tabs and Firefox Performance Issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-tabs

Consider having some thousands of regular 's, input buttons (with jQuery .button() UI) and input texts on a page.

On Firefox, if I click a button click event triggers instantly.

But, if I put all these objects into a jQuery Tab, it takes some time to open a select menu or trigger click of a button.

On Chrome, with or without tabs, everything trigger instantly.

Please check this link http://jsbin.com/awubo3/5/edit on Firefox, then remove the comment on tabs and try again. Buttons will trigger a bit late when tabs are enabled.

On my page it's even worse, sometimes it takes 3-4 seconds to trigger click, or open select menu.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: just tried it and can't replicate. did you try a different machine? what firefox version are you using? any other plugins installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page definitely has some performance issues.  Because of the intensive work you are putting the page through, you are seeing first hand the difference in performance between javascript engine implementations.  There is not much you can do about this other than try and find a more efficient method of doing what you want to do.

For example, you could keep your code architecture the same, but reduce the number of elements on the page.  Implement some sort of paging solution to allow the users to get to all the records, but restrict the number viewed so performance is acceptable.

If you had to have all that information displayed at the same time, consider implementing lighter weight versions of the jquery UI elements you are using.  Implementing a 'tabbing' system can be very lightweight ([here is an example](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/) that is done in very few lines of code).  If you are using the UI Button purely for style reasons, see how much you can achieve with css alone.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery, for all it's strengths, takes the long way around to do things. Consider $(#element) versus getElementByID. the later is built into javascript, and if you have a lot of them, running pure javascript is faster. But the jQuery selector goes through a bunch of jQuery functions calls. Also, stepping through I found that jQuery also clones a lot. Say you give it a anonymous function in a click handler.jQuery does not just attach the event and be done with it. Instead it takes that function, runs through a bunch of isString, isObject, isArray, and finally isFunction. Once it finds out it's a function, it rips it apart and rebuilds the whole thing in a private internal function, then it can attach it to the event.